# Should I get RTX 3090 for my old build with i7-6700 (For machine learning)?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, pc

I have an old build which I bought used and want to use it for deep learning. Should I buy a brand new PC or buy an RTX 3090 and use it with the old build?

Here are the current specs:
i7-6700
Gigabyte Z170-HD3P-CF
12GB RAM DDR4 SDRAM (3 x 4GB)
MSI GTX 960 OC 2GB

If brand new, what CPU and motherboard would be best?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use your old PC, but I doubt your PSU is strong enough to run a 3090 at full power (350W with spikes up to 600W). Maybe it's better to get a 3070, or get a 1000W PSU with the 3090

Answer (score 1):

like was said, for *an old build* it'll likely be your PSU that causes headaches.

The https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170-HD3P-rev-10#ov
looks like a good motherboard, it has the one required PCI-3.0 Express x16 slot.

- You'll need a big enough tower to house the rtx graphics card, along with acceptable cooling/airflow; don't overlook potential fan noise.

  - https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3090-3090ti/
  - 12.3" x 5.4" by 3 slots
  - RTX3090 is 350w, RTX3090ti is 450w, stated required system power PSU is 850w and 950w respectively; in my opinion at least a 600w quality PSU to support then expected 350w potential of the RTX3090 plus mobo+cpu+ram.
  - you may need to sacrifice other installed pci cards to fix the graphics card
  - RTX3090 requires 2 x PCIe 8-pin supplemental power connector from PSU, RTX3090ti requires 3 x PCIe 8-pin
- DDR4 motherboard ram is fine, but 12gb may not be enough; the mobo supports up to 64gb via 4x16 dimms

Comment: Really nice you are poining at the potential problems I missed like cooling and room in the case. I do think though 12GB RAM is enough to run deep learning if you offload most of the work to the 3090 (which already has 24GB RAM on it's own)